# How to prevent blockquote's footer from appearing as global footer on print page

Tags: html, css

I've got a page, which contains some citations in `blockquotes`, with the associated source in a nested `footer` element.

For instance

```
<!-- some html content -->

<blockquote>
 My very looooong citation about something ............
<footer>
  <cite> The Jungle book, p. 43 </cite>
 </footer>
</blockquote>

<! -- more html -->
```

The problem is that when I print the page, the content from the `footer` element gets added to the global footer of the printed page.

Any solution?

Comment: Which browser does that? I cannot reproduce this in Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: Im using the latest version of chrome on Windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MDN on `<footer>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/footer):

> The  HTML element represents a footer for its nearest ancestor sectioning content or sectioning root element

As `<blockquote>` is not *sectioning content*, it’s not valid to use the `<footer>` element inside it to provide additional information for the quote. (Sectioning content elements are article, aside, nav, section. Finally body will be the referenced element.)

Instead, the next ancestor sectioning content is used. In your case I’m assuming that that content is spread on several pages, therefore the footer is repeated as well.

You could wrap the quote in a sectioning element, but it seems semantically more correct to simply not use the `<footer>` element. `<cite>` is already doing enough.

Comment: Thanks. We were told by our accessibility auditor that we needed to use `footer` elements in `blockquote`s. And yes the content is spread on several pages